# How to set selected value in drop list in HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql

How to set selected value in drop list in HTML in Edit Form?

The selected value came from MySql

This code is not work !! >> selected=""

```
<select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender" selected="<?php echo $Gender ?>">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you show us the php code.

Comment: It is not how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 13, accepted):

W3Schools does a good job of explaining this here
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Your code might look something like this.

```
 <select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender">
      <option value="Male" <?php if($Gender == "Male") echo "selected"; ?>>Male</option>
      <option value="Female" <?php if($Gender == "Female") echo "selected"; ?>>Female</option>
 </select>
```

Though my PHP syntax may be a little off, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Selected goes on the `option` tag, not on the `select` tag.

```
<select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender" >
<option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender">
    <option value="Male" <?php if($Gender=='Male') echo 'selected' ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="Female" <?php if($Gender=='Female') echo 'selected' ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` attribute appears on the option(s) that should be selected, not the select element (if it went on the select element itself, then (since multiple options can be selected at the same time) it would have to take a list of `id`s and you would need to add an id to each option).

```
<option value="foo" selected>Foo</option>
```

Generally you would have an array of values (or of value/human text pairs) that you would loop over. (i.e. you wouldn't hard code your options)

You would generate one option each time you went around the loop, and test to see if you should include a selected attribute each time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what you're looking for

Comment: @NamshanNet — I've reread your question … and as far as I can tell … yes, it is. Perhaps you should rephrase your question (or explain what is missing from this answer) … since every other answer you have made that comment on is along similar lines to this one (so if I'm misunderstanding, then I'm not alone).

Answer (score 0):

```
<option <?php if($Gender == 'Male'){ echo(' selected '); } ?> value="Male">Male</option>
<option <?php if($Gender == 'Female'){ echo(' selected '); } ?> value="Female">Female</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender">

<?php
$genders = array( 'Male', 'Female' );
foreach( $genders as $value )
{
    $selected = ( $Gender == $value )? ' selected="selected"': '';
    echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . $selected . '>' . $value . '</option>';
}
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

just another way of doing it. I prefer to use shorthand if statements for code such as this.

```
<select name="TutorGender" id=\"TutorGender\">
  <option value="Male" <?php echo ($Gender == "Male" ? "selected" : ""); ?>>Male</option>
  <option value="Female" <?php echo ($Gender == "Female" ? "selected" : ""); ?>>Female</option>
```

here is a [link](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) to using shorthand "if" statements.

Answer (score 0):

In a case where I needed to use a select as part of a user update form that was populated via a database I found the array option works best. The line by line option can get very unwieldy very quickly. This way you simply need to add an option to the $optionDept array should any new options be required. In this example "$row['Dept']" is from the larger overarching results from the database request.

```
$optionDept= array('sales','warehouse','inspection','production','accounts','admin','inactive');

$optionCount= count($optionDept);

echo"<select name=\"UserDept\">";
for($x = 0; $x < $optionCount; $x++) {
echo"<option value=".$optionDept[$x];
if($optionDept[$x]==$row['Dept']){echo " selected";}
echo">".$optionDept[$x]."</option>";}
echo"</select</P>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

if you want to keep male as selected

```
<select name="TutorGender" id="TutorGender" >
<option value="Male" selected="selected">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what you're looking for

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me: I send througt the GET method of the submit the value i want to restore, and then in the php, AT THE END OF THE PAGE (if not, default values will be set if the code is before the php) i set those values.

```
echo "select_language.selectedIndex = ".$_GET['iL'].";";
```

Comment: you really should use basic HTML (that is, set the selected attribute on the option element of your choice), and not resort to using javascript hacks.